# What is this tall cylindrical plumbing device, connected to my water line, with a ticking black box and an electrical wire?

Tags: plumbing

Another interesting contraption in a new home. Does anyone know what it is?

It’s connected to plumbing pipes coming out of the ground beside house.

It has a ticking timer on the top in that black box. And it has an electrical wire plugged into a wall adapter.

It has inflow and outflow connections and outflow goes into the wall. It also has a drain rubber house that goes somewhere under ground outside.

[image]

Comment: This has absolutely no label? No numbers or letters embossed in the plastic housing anywhere? No identifying marks whatsoever? Did you ask questions of the seller, real estate agent or inspector when you were looking at the house?

Comment: Do you have a well, or are you on municipal/public water supply? If the latter, test results should be available from the water supplier for free (they have to test regularly) and the odds of it being GAC because someone didn't like the level of chlorine they were tasting go way up.

Comment: Only model number I got was in the timer that’s how I know it’s a timer. The cylinder has a space for a label but no label.  

It’s connected to a municipal waterline.

Comment: Look up the timer model number to see who makes it. It's probably branded the same as the device it's attached to.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks suspiciously like a water softener by waterfilterone.com, going by the shape of the chamber (esp. its 45deg bevel at the top) and the controller/valve unit.

If the brine tank/barrel is missing (it's not in the picture), this may be a **decommissioned** unit, as also suggested by the painting-over of the decal.

[image]

More: at https://waterfilterone.com/blogs/news/the-definitive-water-softener-installation-guide

Comment: @Ecnerwal, fair, and not being there, it's all conjecture on my behalf. I suspect the hose is removed and the softener is haphazardly decommissioned, but left "on" (running) so that the valves remain open or out of unplug-anxiety. If you spot a filter with such a tank & controller, then sure, that could be it too. The OP could unplug it and open the controller for any further labeling, or scrub the plaque, or look for the brine hose connection using the linked info

Comment: @Ecnerwal I am certainly not disagreeing with you, but linking to a site called "watersoftenerparts.com" to disprove it's a water softener is... well... perhaps not the strongest argument ;) Let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 0):

Water Softener.  Used to take minerals and other "hardness" out of the incoming water supply.  Typically there will be a large bin for salt that it uses for it's softening process, but I'm not seeing it in your picture, so perhaps this uses some other method than using salt for softening.

Comment: let's just call it a "water conditioner" so we can't be wrong.

Comment: Resin beds look similar for some types part of a conditioner

Comment: So if it’s a filter, does it ever need the filter changed? Or backwash flushes everything out?